# Disable email notification for specific customers

Tags: magento2, email, magento2.3

Please can any one help me on this,
I would like to disable email notofication for customers, which have a flag  non_email_customers set to true.
I Have Try this way. i have created a  plugin for: `Magento\Framework\Mailsend\TransportInterface::sendMessage()`

but I don't know how to get customer object there. Getting it from customer session is not the best solution I suppose beacuse of mail from adminhtml area. Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all the customers with this code -

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    ...
}

/**
 * Get customer collection
 */
public function getCustomerCollection()
{
    return $this->_customerFactory->create();
}
```

Use this as -

```
$customerCollection = $this->getCustomerCollection();

foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {
    echo $customer->getEmail(); //Or any other method
}
```

Since non_email_customers sounds like a user defined field, you should be able to access it as `$customer->getDataByKey('non_email_customers');`

To get a list of all the methods available on the $customer object, use `get_class_methods($customer)`

Hope this helps!